# iPad app problem displaying image in webview via html

Tags: iphone, html, ipad, sdk, webview

I am working on one iPad app, I have few html files which i displays in webview.
Some images in the html are not showing up. I found common thing in this images are that they their dimensions are more than 2000x2000 px. What could be the problem please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Needs a bit more info I think. Can you link to some example images? Does this happen with all large images, even external ones?

Answer (score 0):

As of now got the solution that these huge dimensions are creating problem... resizing the image worked for me...